# number of ways evaluation of expression such that value not changed

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, combinatorics, permutations

one example:

> How many ways we can do possible value-preserving parenthesis the following expression in such a way that value not changed after parenthesis with one constraint that parenthesis among one variable is not correct (i.e: $(i)+j+k$ is not acceptable) ?

as an example for expression $i+j+k$, parenthesis like $i+(j+k)$, $((i+j)+k)$ are correct parenthesis but $(i)+j+k$ is not. I take a complete short example as follows.

Comment: I think your definition of "correct parenthesis" needs to be made more precise. Why, for example, is $(i)$ excluded and not $((i+j))$? Also, are $i+j+k$ and $(i+j)+k$ different, even though the second one just shows the consequence of the conventional rules for parsing? Similarly, do the redundant outer parentheses in $((i+j)+k)$ really create a different expression than $(i+j)+k$?

Comment: $i+j-k$ has only two complete parenthesizations, corresponding to the two possible parse trees. The number of evaluations of an unparenthedized binary expression with $k$ operators, or equivalently the number of balanced parenthesis strings with $k$ pairs of parentheses, is given by $C_k$, the $k_{th}$ [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). (The linked wikipedia article has lots of info and useful links). Your (rather unclear) definition double-counts, so its less combinatorically useful.

Comment: And your statement that "each operator can have parentheses or not" undercounts the possible arrangements, since parentheses do not have a single possible location for an operator. The Catalan numbers griw more rapidly than powers of two; $C_5 = 42$ and $C_6 = 132$.

Comment: Finally note that the number of possible value-preserving reparenthesizations can depend on algebraic identities. For example, the value of $(i-i)*(\text{whatever})$ does not depend on any aspect of the complicated expression inside the second pair of parentheses.

Comment: You still don't define "correct parentheses". Also this is disorganized. Also it's not clear what question you are trying to ask. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag unneeded comments.

Comment: (@EmmaNic. must have been in "half-RPN-mode".)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3962781/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133715/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove its content.  That is considered "vandalism" on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I would need to consult with other moderators about deleting this, since there are some comments here that are relevant to the question that remains open on Math.SE.

Comment: @EmmaNic. instead of whining you could have improved your question.

Comment: I do not plan to delete this question.  As a general rule, we don't delete questions that the system doesn't let you delete.

Answer (score 1):

1. What's wrong with (i) + j + k ?
2. I live in a world where floating-point arithmetic has rounding errors, and where integer arithmetic has overflow checks, so (i + j) + k and i + (j + k) are most definitely not the same, for example if i is a large positive integer, and j, k are two large negative integers then the second one can produce an overflow (crash) while the first one doesn't.

Comment: @EmmaNic., if this does not meet your requirements, please edit your question to make it clearer what you are asking and state your requirements clearly, so that others don't have a similar reaction.

Comment: Emma Nic: Very, very rude. I have not the slightest intent to remove my answer.

Comment: You think me telling you that (a + b) + c and a + (b + c) usually don't give the same result is "a strange answer"? That's how it is.